# How do I clean this grey stain from my bathtub?

Tags: bathroom, cleaning, bathtub, stain-removal

Below is an image of my bathtub, which has this grey stain. I just moved in and it was already there so I don't know what caused it.

1. Is this possible to clean?
2. If it is possible, what do I use? (I would prefer a link to a product on Amazon if possible)
3. What caused it?
4. Is this preventable?

[image: bathtub with grey stain]

Comment: My gut on this one is that it is from a bathroom anti-slip mat. one of the ones with suction cups. The person who lived there before probably "never" picked it up and cleaned under it. That is probably years worth of grime/dirt sanding its way into the tubs finish. You can try scrubbing bubbles products, or amonia, or even oven-off, I'm recommending some crazy ideas here, at least from the picture it looks pretty worked in, so even a buffing machine could help, then you have to refinish it. Crazy ideas... but its going to take some scrubbing and then polish

Comment: I'm renting the place and will likely leave in a year. Do you think the effort is worth it for me to clean it?

Comment: No. It is not your tub. But you should take a photo and discuss with the landlord. At least there will be no impact to your security when you move. you could always install an anti slip mat as well.

Comment: It being mine or not doesn't bother me. I care more about how much time it will take. If it'll make a couple hours max, I'll do it. But if I have to clean it every day for a week, that's more effort than I care to do

Answer (score 2):

When I moved into my apartment last year it was disgusting the tub was worse than your pic. I sprayed with clorox and used comet and after a few time of cleaning it looked beautiful...just a bit of elbow grease!  good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Welcome to Home Improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Try some Bon Ami or Barkeepers Friend. I have a hard time finding Bon Ami but Home Depot sells Barkeepers Friend. These should remove the stain without scratching the porcelain.

Comment: It's already scratched, you can see the coat is "gone"

Comment: The glaze may not be gone. I have a tub that gets similar marks; it was manufactured with a pattern of dull spots to effect an anti-slip finish. Over time it gets discolored from soap and dirt clinging to the dull spots. I am able to make it look bright and clean with Comet Cleanser, a scouring sponge, and a bit of elbow grease. @Jerry P.'s suggestion is a good one.

Comment: Note that Comet is far more abrasive than the other 2 I mentioned and will eventually rub away all the porcelain down to raw metal.

Comment: True, comet works, but it's like sandpaper. So do the rest of you feel that based on OP answer about hours and the approach to cleaning it for years, he should do as @JerryP suggested and then use glaze/coating kit from a big box store? In the long run, it will take less time. OP: it will take a good portion of a day, and then you have to let it cure, but the result will be less future elbow scrubbing - Oh, personally, I would still take a picture and discuss with the landlord. I know all landlords are not created equal, but as I am one, I would want to know, and I might even do it myself 4 u.

Comment: Rebuttal regarding Comet, I installed a Kohler cast-iron kitchen sink in 1995 which gets scrubbed at least once a week with Comet (which, by the way was recommended by Kohler for the sink at that time) and it looks brand new to this day, no reduction of gloss or apparent wear.

Answer (score 0):

I used lime away and then a Mr. clean magic eraser. Worked great!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.